# How do I set an initially opened expansion panel to be closed by default?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

I have a sidenav with a tab group and an accordion panel.

The problem is that everything works, but when I get to the part where the expansion panel's title is, the expansion panel is open.

In fact, the first time you click, it reopens even though it is open by default, so I need it to be closed by default (I would like it to appear closed and you have to click to open, the toggle already works when you click open/close, but I want it to appear **closed by default**)

*You can see it in this gif:*

[image: GIF of initially opened accordion panel on sidenav]

`tabs-nav.component.html`

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs-sidenav">
    <div routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="back2Main()" style="cursor:pointer" class="vertical-align-text">Menú</div>
    <div *ngIf="numItemsSelected >= 1">&nbsp;<mat-icon>chevron_right</mat-icon>
    </div>
    <span *ngIf="numItemsSelected >= 1" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" class="vertical-align-text" style="cursor:pointer;vertical-align: middle;" (click)="toBreadcrum1();">&nbsp;{{breadcrumb1.option}}</span>
    <div *ngIf="numItemsSelected >= 2">&nbsp;<mat-icon>chevron_right</mat-icon></div>
   <span *ngIf="numItemsSelected >= 2" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" class="vertical-align-text" style="cursor:pointer" (click)="toBreadcrum2();">&nbsp;{{breadcrumb2.option}}</span>
    <div *ngIf="numItemsSelected >= 3">&nbsp;<mat-icon>chevron_right</mat-icon></div>
   <span *ngIf="numItemsSelected >= 3" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" class="vertical-align-text" style="cursor:pointer" (click)="toBreadcrum3();">&nbsp;{{breadcrumb3.option}}</span>
   </div>
<div class="style-sidenav">
    <mat-tab-group class="navigation-tabs" [selectedIndex]="currentSelectedRootTab" dynamicHeight style="width:20vw; background-color:white">
        <mat-tab *ngFor="let rootTab of rootTabs; let rootIndex = index" [label]="rootIndex">
            <mat-nav-list>
        <div *ngFor="let rootOption of rootTab.options; let optionIndex = index;">
          <a mat-list-item *ngIf="!rootOption.rootTab && !rootOption.options" [routerLink]="rootOption.route" routerLinkActive="active"><mat-icon>{{rootOption.icon}}</mat-icon>{{rootOption.option}}</a>
          <mat-accordion *ngIf="rootOption.options">
              <mat-expansion-panel>
              <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                  {{rootOption.option}}
                </mat-panel-title>
              </mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <div *ngFor="let option of rootOption.options"
                   class="option-routes"
                   [routerLink]="option.route">
                <mat-icon>{{option.icon}}</mat-icon><span class="option-label">{{option.label}}</span>
              </div>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
          </mat-accordion>
          <a mat-list-item style="width:100%; color: #777777;" *ngIf="rootOption.rootTab" (click)="rootSelected(optionIndex, rootOption.rootTab, rootOption)"><mat-icon>{{rootOption.icon}}</mat-icon>{{rootOption.option}}<div><mat-icon style="padding-left:0%;">chevron_right</mat-icon></div></a>
        </div>
            </mat-nav-list>
        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

`tabs-nav.component.ts`

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
  selector: 'app-tabs-nav',
  templateUrl: './tabs-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs-nav.component.css']
})
export class TabsNavComponent {
  currentSelectedRootTab = 0;
  previousRootTab = 0;
  indexClicked = 0;
  numItemsSelected = 0;
  breadcrumb1;
  breadcrumb2;
  breadcrumb3;
  rootTabs = [
    {
      id: 0,
      options: [ // Aquí van las fijas, que no tienen ni drop ni transición //
        { option: 'Home', route: '/dashboard', icon: 'home' },
        { option: 'Link 1', route: '/parametros', icon: 'tune' },
        { option: 'Link 2', route: '/operativas', icon: 'settings' },
        { option: 'Link 3', route: '/productos', icon: 'layers' },
        { option: 'More', rootTab: 1, icon: 'flash_on' } // Esta si tiene transición //
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      options: [
        { option: 'OPTION 1', rootTab: 2 },
        { option: 'OPTION 2', rootTab: 4 },
        { option: 'OPTION 3', rootTab: 5 }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      options: [
        {
          option: 'Portal Dropdown',
          route: '/Submenu1',
          options: [
            { label: 'Option 1', route: '/Submenu1', icon: 'filter_1' },
            { label: 'Option 2', route: '/Submenu2', icon: 'filter_2' },
            { label: 'Option 3', route: '/Submenu3', icon: 'filter_3' },
            { label: 'Option 4', route: '/Submenu4', icon: 'filter_4' },
            { label: 'Option 5', route: '/Submenu5', icon: 'filter_5' },
          ]
        },
        // { option: 'TestJustIgnore', route: '/Submenu2' },
        // { option: 'TestJustIgnore', route: '/Submenu3' },
        {
          option: 'Second Dropdown',
          route: '/Submenu4',
          options: [
            { label: 'Option 1', route: '/Submenu1', icon: 'filter_1' },
            { label: 'Option 2', route: '/Submenu2', icon: 'filter_2' }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3, options: [
        { option: 'put additional options here' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      options: [
        {
          option: 'Portal Dropdown',
          route: '/Submenu1',
          options: [
            { label: 'Option 1', route: '/Submenu1', icon: 'filter_1' },
            { label: 'Option 2', route: '/Submenu2', icon: 'filter_2' },
            { label: 'Option 3', route: '/Submenu3', icon: 'filter_3' },
            { label: 'Option 4', route: '/Submenu4', icon: 'filter_4' },
            { label: 'Option 5', route: '/Submenu5', icon: 'filter_5' },
          ]
        },
        // { option: 'TestJustIgnore', route: '/Submenu2' },
        // { option: 'TestJustIgnore', route: '/Submenu3' },
        {
          option: 'Branches',
          route: 'Second Dropdown',
          options: [
            { label: 'Option 1', route: '/Submenu1', icon: 'filter_1' },
            { label: 'Option 2', route: '/Submenu2', icon: 'filter_2' }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      options: [
        {
          option: 'Portal Dropdown',
          route: '/Submenu1',
          options: [
            { label: 'Option 1', route: '/Submenu1', icon: 'filter_1' },
            { label: 'Option 2', route: '/Submenu2', icon: 'filter_2' },
            { label: 'Option 3', route: '/Submenu3', icon: 'filter_3' },
            { label: 'Option 4', route: '/Submenu4', icon: 'filter_4' },
            { label: 'Option 5', route: '/Submenu5', icon: 'filter_5' },
          ]
        },
        // { option: 'TestJustIgnore', route: '/Submenu2' },
        // { option: 'TestJustIgnore', route: '/Submenu3' },
        {
          option: 'Second Dropdown',
          route: '/Submenu4',
          options: [
            { label: 'Option 1', route: '/Submenu1', icon: 'filter_1' },
            { label: 'Option 2', route: '/Submenu2', icon: 'filter_2' }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ];
  rootSelected(optionIndex, optionRootIndex, rootOption) {
    this.numItemsSelected++;
    this.previousRootTab = this.currentSelectedRootTab;
    this.currentSelectedRootTab = optionRootIndex;
    this.indexClicked = optionIndex;
    if (!this.breadcrumb1) {
      this.breadcrumb1 = rootOption;
    } else if (!this.breadcrumb2) {
      this.breadcrumb2 = rootOption;
    } else {
      this.breadcrumb3 = rootOption;
    }
  }
  back2Main() {
    this.currentSelectedRootTab = 0;
    this.previousRootTab = 0;
    this.indexClicked = 0;
    this.numItemsSelected = 0;
    this.breadcrumb1 = null;
    this.breadcrumb2 = null;
    this.breadcrumb3 = null;
  }
  toBreadcrum1() {
    if (this.numItemsSelected > 1) {
      this.currentSelectedRootTab = this.breadcrumb1.rootTab;
      this.breadcrumb2 = null;
      this.numItemsSelected--;
    }
  }
  toBreadcrum2() {
    if (this.numItemsSelected > 2) {
      this.currentSelectedRootTab = this.breadcrumb2.rootTab;
      this.breadcrumb3 = null;
      this.numItemsSelected--;
    }
  }
}
```

`tabs-nav.component.css`

```css
::ng-deep .navigation-tabs .mat-tab-label-container{
  display:none;
}

.breadcrumbs-sidenav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin:1% ;
  height:10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 2.5px;
  padding-left: 2.5px;
}

.style-sidenav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color:white;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 25px;
}


/* .vertical-align-text {
      padding-top: 1.5px;
      font-size: 13px;
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
} */

.mat-expansion-panel:not([class*=mat-elevation-z]) {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.option-routes {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 35px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #777777;
}

/* .option-label {
  margin-left: 10px;
} */

.material-icons {
    float: left;
}

.mat-icon {
  color: #fbc837;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.mat-list-item, .mat-list-text, .mat-submenu-title, .mat-accordion, .vertical-align-text, .mat-expansion-panel-header-title { /* Color of the Sidenav Text */
  color: #777777;

}


.mat-expansion-indicator {
  color: #fbc837;
}

.mat-expansion-panel-header {
  height: 48px;
}
```

I'm using Angular version 5.2.0 and I can't update it, so I need a solution with this version.

Comment: Could you please provide a stackblitz ? seems a problem with your implementation.

Comment: In the Stackblitz everything works ok, you can see it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5xefi-k81zfl


I do not know if it is my version of Angular or whatever the problem is, since Stackblitz is using version 7 and I am using 5.2.0 in my project, it is not a solution for me to actually update the project version, that's why I'm looking for a solution that can apply to this version; either through CSS or something.

Comment: `rootOption.options` is is becoming true before `selectedIndex` setting to 2.That is causing the problem. It's happening from `mat-tab`.try to find a work around

Comment: @Arkhi Aki thanks for your answer, 
I'm still trying but I have not found a solution yet, and it seems to be a visual nonsense but at the user experience level I think it's very important